# How would you add a share to smb.conf via a script?

Tags: bash, configuration, samba, shell

I'd like to script adding a share to a `smb.conf` file. My current script just appends it to the end of the file, but that's not ideal. I'd rather have something that will add a new share if it doesn't exist, and replace it if it does.

I'm currently scripting this on a CentOS 7 distro, but would ideally like something that would work across distros, though that's not a requirement.

Also, I'm using `bash` to do this because the script is run before other packages are added to the system. The script uses `yum` to install the `samba` packages, and then is supposed to configure it and add shares.

Comment: Check for pre-existing modules for your favourite scripting language. For example, I quickly found [File::Samba](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Samba) for perl

Comment: Can you tell us more about the environment and context of what you are doing?  If I had a server and I wanted to programmatically change shares often, then I would create a directory, setup an include for that directory.  Then I would just place one file per share in that directory.

Comment: @glennjackman - That would be ideal, but I was hoping to not have to add additional scripting languages and packages. This is part of an rpm and I'd rather not have a lot of pre-requirements. If I'm going to do that, I might as well use saltstack, puppet, chef or another tool like that. I was hoping for something more lightweight. Too bad there isn't a smbconfmerge command. I wonder what saltstack uses?

Answer (score 9):

To fit with modern sysadmin best practices it would be good to add your configs as individual files in `/etc/smb/smb.d` and then reference them with an `include`.  Sadly samba does not support wildcard `include`s so you have to do add something like:

```
include = /etc/smb/includes.conf
```

in your `smb.conf` and then generate the `includes.conf` with something like:

```
ls /etc/smb/smb.d/* | sed -e 's/^/include = /' > /etc/smb/includes.conf
```

For a bit more context:

```
chicks@silver 23:57:23 smb !531 $ ls smb.d
a.conf  c.conf  e.conf
chicks@silver 23:57:29 smb !532 $ ls /etc/smb/smb.d/* | sed -e 's/^/include = /' > /etc/smb/includes.conf
chicks@silver 23:57:40 smb !533 $ cat includes.conf 
include = /etc/smb/smb.d/a.conf
include = /etc/smb/smb.d/c.conf
include = /etc/smb/smb.d/e.conf
```

So now you can stick any additional samba configs into `/etc/smb/smb.d`, regenerate `includes.conf` and restart samba and life is good.

Comment: Is that independent of the distro? Also, how does that work if you want to update parameters as well as add/remove shares?

Comment: Yep, that should work well regardless of distro (unless the distro comes with something like this already, but I haven't seen one yet). It'd be the same procedure no matter what you're changing: make x.conf changes/additions/removal, rebuild includes.conf, restart the daemon.

Comment: This doesn't work with global settings. It also doesn't fix the issue that a particular share name could be added to one of the a.conf, b.conf, or c.conf files already.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you from grepping through all of the configs and making sure they are up to some standard.  You could use a similar mechanism for global settings too.  One include for global settings would point to `*.conf` and another for shares would point to `*.share`.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html would be another way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old topic but still useful.
This are my scripts to create and delete users in a simple samba installation for storing backups.

**Tested on CentOS**

**Prepare directory and permissions**

Run this commands on a terminal

```
sudo mkdir /backups
sudo mkdir /etc/samba/smb.conf.d
sudo groupadd sambashare 
sudo chgrp sambashare /backups
sudo useradd -M -d /home/sadmin -s /usr/sbin/nologin -G sambashare sadmin
sudo smbpasswd -a sadmin
sudo smbpasswd -e sadmin
```

**smb.conf**

```
[global]
    workgroup = TUAITI
    security = user

    passdb backend = tdbsam

    printing = cups
    printcap name = cups
    load printers = yes
    cups options = raw

include = /etc/samba/includes.conf
```

**smbaddshare.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=$1
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    echo "No username given"
    exit 1
fi

useradd -M -d /backups/$USER -s /usr/sbin/nologin -G sambashare $USER
mkdir /backups/$USER
chown $USER:sambashare /backups/$USER
chmod 2770 /backups/$USER
smbpasswd -a $USER
smbpasswd -e $USER

cat  /etc/samba/smb.conf.d/$USER.conf
[$USER]
    path = /backups/$USER
    browseable = no
    read only = no
    force create mode = 0660
    force directory mode = 2770
    valid users = $USER @sadmin
EOF

ls /etc/samba/smb.conf.d/* | sed -e 's/^/include = /' > /etc/samba/includes.conf

smbcontrol all reload-config
```

**smbremoveshare.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=$1
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    echo "No username given"
    exit 1
fi

read -r -p "Are you sure you want to delete the user ? [y/N] " response
response=${response,,}    # tolower
if [[ "$response" =~ ^(yes|y)$ ]]
then
    smbpasswd -x $USER
    userdel $USER
    mv /backups/$USER /backups/$USER.`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`.deleted
    rm /etc/samba/smb.conf.d/$USER.conf

    ls /etc/samba/smb.conf.d/* | sed -e 's/^/include = /' > /etc/samba/includes.conf

    smbcontrol all reload-config
else
    echo "Nothing done"
fi
```